# Convergence of power series dependent on parameter

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to prove that  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{n^{\alpha}(1+nx^2)}}$$ converges for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ whenever $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$. How can I prove this. Which test I have to use?

Comment: As the question is currently put, we can do better than $\alpha\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The series converges for any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Okay and what is the reason? how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

As noticed in the comment section, the power series is converging for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, provided $\alpha > 0$.

Indeed, if $x = 0$ then the power series is $0$ (since there is $x$ in the numerator and the denominator is different from $0$). If $x \neq 0$, we have that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Big|\frac{x}{n^{\alpha}(1 + nx^2)}\Big| \le \sum \frac{|x|}{n^{1 + \alpha}x^2} = \frac{1}{|x|}\sum_{n = 1}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{n^{1 + \alpha}} < \infty.$$

This proves that the power series is convergent for all $\alpha > 0$. If $\alpha = 0$ notice that the series at $x = 1$ diverges, indeed we have the tail of the harmonic series: $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 + n} = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$

Divergence for $\alpha < 0$ follows similarly.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality?

Comment: $n^{\alpha} + n^{1 + \alpha}x^2 \ge n^{1 + \alpha}x^2$ hence the reciprocal satisfies the opposite inequality.